# accessible currency numbers with React Native

Tags: react-native, accessibility

I am working on a fully accessible banking app and I need to display currency numbers within a list of transactions such as `-19,99€` or `75,20€`.

No matter what I do, I can't find a working solution for both Android and iOS.

Let's analyze how `-19,99€` is read on
Android Talkback will read "minus nineteen comma nine nine" (in French)
iOS Voiceover will read "nineteen euros nineteen nine cents" (in French)

So basically Android is not reading the currency symbol and iOS is not reading the minus sign.

Anyone already solved this?
I would like to avoid going down the path of converting numbers to words because we will want to localize our app and it will create a lot of complexity.

Comment: I don't have an iOS device to check, but Mac/VoiceOver reads `&minus;` HTML encode for minus instead of the `-` (dash) as "minus 19 99 euro". I would suggest using that.